# Implementing Array#flatten

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to implement `Array#flatten`. This implementation removes all nested arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]]]

def my_flatten(arr)
  arr.reduce([]) do |result, item| 
    item.is_a?(Array) ? result + my_flatten(item) : result << item
  end
end

my_flatten(a) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Prompt how to implement such behavior

```
a.flatten(1) #=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a parameter to specify the max depth (defaulting to `nil`) and a parameter to keep track of the current depth (0 on the initial call and then incremented by 1 on each recursive call):

```
def my_flatten(arr, max_depth = nil, current_depth = 0)
    arr.reduce([]) do |result, item| 
      item.is_a?(Array) && (max_depth.nil? || current_depth < max_depth) ? 
        result + my_flatten(item, max_depth, current_depth + 1) : result << item
    end
end
```

You could replace the `?:` with an `if/else` if you felt this was more readable:

```
def my_flatten(arr, max_depth = nil, current_depth = 0)
  arr.reduce([]) do |result, item|
    if item.is_a?(Array) && (max_depth.nil? || current_depth < max_depth)
      result + my_flatten(item, max_depth, current_depth + 1)
    else
      result << item
    end
  end
end
```

This now returns the expected results:

```
 my_flatten(a) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

 my_flatten(a, 1) #=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I created something similar a long time back. Here is the [gist link](https://gist.github.com/suryart/235b3ef829e21471b229784188a6473a#file-my_flatten-rb).

Code from gist:

```
class Array
  def my_flatten(level = nil)
    rb_flatten(self, [], level)
  end

  private
  # apply recursion based on the level
  # when no level provided, then produce a complete flatten array
  # when level is given, then produce a flatten array flattened till that certain level
  def rb_flatten(array, result, level)
    array.each do |value|
      if ((value.is_a? Array) && (level.nil? || (level && level > 0)))
        rb_flatten(value, result, (level.nil? ? level : ((level || 0 ) - 1)))
      else
        result << value
      end
    end
    return result
  end
end
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `Proc` like this.

```
class Array
  def my_flatten(level = nil)
    p = ->(arr, exp, lvl) do
      arr.each { |val| Array === val && (!level || lvl < level) ? p.(val, exp, lvl+1) : exp << val }
      exp
    end

    p.(self, [], 0)
  end
end

a = [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]]]
p a.my_flatten
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p a.my_flatten(0)
# => [1, 2, [3, [4, 5]]]
p a.my_flatten(1)
# => [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
p a.my_flatten(2)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```